# Android - Start a program immediately on startup of device

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Hello everyone and thanks for your trouble,

I have a program [detailed here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/make-your-next-android-app-a-good-listener/#). This uses a microphone icon in order to start listening for voice. However, I want this program to run immediately on start up of the device. How is this possible? Also, I want the program to run without any visuals and simply return the text translation to my running program, which will take care of what command to execute. Any help on any of these topics? It will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it'd be helpful if you could paste relevant pieces of code into the question instead of pointing to some other site. That would help the readers ie. your possible helpers. You might want to explain what is the exact problem and why do you think your approach doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. For this you'll need set permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, define your service and listener for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` action:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:label="My Service">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.myapp.MyService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
    android:name=".receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then you have to define the receiver that will get the `BOOT_COMPLETED` action and start your service.

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MySystemService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps .. :)